# Metric to assess similarity of distributions

Tags: distributions, similarities, synthetic-data

I am working on clinical synthetic data and I would like to learn more about metrics to compare synthetic vs measurements distributions.

As there are methods to generate synthetic distributions with given constraints extracted from measurements,

I wonder whether you have pointers for metric definition apt to assess whether a synthetic distribution can be used as surrogate of a measured one.

I think that classical metrics have been often used to do that, but I can't find a review assessing the errors which have been introduced.
I will be grateful for any suggestions.
Andrea

PS E.g. I was wondering whether a vector containing classical distribution descriptors like mean, median, skewness, kurtosis for each distribution could be used taking their correlation as a value of similarity (i.e. if correlation = 1 there is high probability that the two distribution could be used as surrogate of one another).... just thinking loud. I could not find anything similar used so far.

Comment: This has been for the most part answered in the thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82076/similarity-measure-between-multiple-distributions. An additional measurement would be: the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) / [Earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).